# Error updating after fooling around with Anbox

Tags: upgrade, pop-os

I was (unsuccessfully) playing around with Anbox on my POP OS distro last week. Turns out my Lenovo T540p ThinkPad isn't geared towards Android emulation. I created a Timeshift backup before installing Anbox and its pre-requisites, and once I found out that my laptop won't run Anbox I ran a sudo apt remove -y anbox and followed that by restoring the Timeshift backup I made before I started playing around.

When I tried to run an update today I got the error shown in the screenshot. It fails when trying to update the Linux headers, but it's trying to find the dkms.conf file in an anbox folder. Does anyone know how I can fix this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out... I used this script to list all the DKMS packages (I'm not sure if they're called packages):

> for i in /var/lib/dkms/*/[^k]*/source; do [ -e "$i" ] || echo
> "$i";done

I found the script here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/227258/error-could-not-locate-dkms-conf-file

Running the script listed to following location:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/source

The solution was to remove the link: /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/source

After that, I was able to run `apt update && apt full-upgrade -y` without any issues